# Kivy Text To Speech

Tags: python, kivy

I was trying to create text to speech with Kivy 2.0.0, python 3.6
I have installed pyttsx3.
I have created a text box and button and a function to speak from text box.

It does speak and work well in computer.
Then I converted to apk and installed it.
When I press Speak button it crash.

My python main file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import pyttsx3


Builder.load_file('tts.kv')

class MyLayout(Widget):
    def speak(self):
        word=self.ids.word_input.text        
        engine=pyttsx3.init()

        volume = engine.getProperty('volume')
        engine.setProperty('volume',1.0)
        engine.say(word)
        engine.runAndWait()
        
        

class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

    

if __name__=="__main__":
    myApp().run()


My kivy file 

<MyLayout>:
    FloatLayout:
        size:root.width,root.height


        TextInput:
            id:word_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint:(.6,.1)
            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'top':.8}


        Button:
            text:"Speak"
            size_hint:(.6, .2)
            font_size:35
            pos_hint:{'center_x':.5,'top':.6}
            on_press:root.speak()
```

How do I make android speak to my inserted text? Something we need to change in Buildozer file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, the `pyttsx3` library only supports desktop application, and that's why I would recommend trying out the [plyer library](https://github.com/kivy/plyer), which aims for direct android/ios support. It's also developed by the team behind the `Kivy` library as well!

```
from plyer import tts

message = "Hello world!"
tts.speak(message=message)
```

Side note: If you are intending of also having this app on Windows, I suggest either sticking to the `pyttsx3` library, or if you want to use `plyer` instead then you must have the `espeak.exe` application in your running directory or `PATH`, you can find it simply by searching for it on google.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem for me still. I check[link](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for speak method ..class plyer.facades.TTS.I may not understanding clearly..I changed accordingly and  still doesn't work.